# What are the various values for the tool flag in hg resolve?

Tags: mercurial

I've seen values of internal:local and internal:merge among other being used for the tool flag in hg resolve.

What are the various options available for the tool flag and what are they used for? Where does the internal configuration stored and what does internal mean?

Thank you.

Comment: The "internal" tools (which do not need a prefix, you can just use `:local` for instance) are built in (it's not clear what you mean by "configuration stored") and are described in the output of `hg help merge-tools`.

Comment: I guess I was asking if "internal" is a keyword? If I had to use an external merge tool, what would I enter instead of internal? Is there anything else that is used generally?

Comment: It's more of a prefix to distinguish these things from external merge tools. The problem is that each tool is referred-to by *name*. If I name my evil external merge tool `zorg`, well, that's fine, there's no internal `zorg`. But then the Mercurial guys decide that evil merges are great and create an internal `zorg`. Now I can't use *my* `zorg`: I get *their* `zorg`. But if they name it `:zorg`, their names will never conflict with my external tool names, which never start with (or even contain) `:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are some internal merge tools which can be used. The internal merge tools are:

- `internal:dump`
- `internal:fail`
- `internal:local`
- `internal:merge`
- `internal:merge-local`
- `internal:merge-other`
- `internal:merge3`
- `internal:other`
- `internal:prompt`
- `internal:tagmerge`
- `internal:union`

https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#merge-tools